# Print repeating digit pattern

Tags: c++

How can I display a repeating pattern of consecutive digits?

This is what I hope to achieve:

> ```
> 1
> 12
> ...
> 123456789
> 1234567890
> 12345678901
> ```

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int i,j,rows;
    cout << "Enter the number of rows: ";
    cin >> rows;
    for(i=1;i<=rows;++i)
    {
        for(j=1;j<=i;++j)
        {
           cout << j << " ";  
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

This will not repeat the characters. How do I make it repeat after 9?

Comment: This will display the numbers as half pyramid to the right.But how to make it repeat the numbers after number 9?

Comment: You could just mod each j by 10. When I run the program with that it does what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Use the modulus operator.

```
std::cout << (j % 10) << ' ';
```